# "site can't be reached error" while downloading TFS 2015 agent

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015

[image]I am getting "site can't be reached" error while trying to download agent from tfs 2015.

Do anyone have idea on what can be done to resolve this?

Comment: Where you are trying to download it from? Have you tried going to your Web Access, then "Settings", "Agent Queues", "Download Agent" ? Alternatively, you could go here, and download the desired agent as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents for either TFS 2015 or newer.

Comment: Please see my edit, I am trying to download Agent from here

Comment: On clicking "Download agent" here, a pop-up should appear, afterwards, you have the options to choose which agent to download. Do you see the popup after clicking on the button? If so, copy the link from the download button in the popup, (or to the clipboard), and provide it here, so we could verify if there is an issue with the link itself, or it is something on your machine that prevents it from a proper download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was clicking on download agent, it was redirecting to some other web address but not to the same IP on which TFS is hosted.

Corrected that, now I am able to download it.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely be something wrong with your internet environment than anything else such as TFS settings/Access/Configurations. Double check if you are behind an especially restrictive corporate firewall, disable the  firewall temporarily.

When you click the **Download** button, TFS will go to this page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=829054; to download the "`vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.xxx.x.zip`" file.

Try to connect to this site from browser directly and download the agent to install.

You could also download the build agents from the [Release site](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases) in GitHub.